# What could be the underlying reasons for the spaces or voids between the layers?

Tags: print-quality, creatbot-f430

I've been attempting to 3D print a hollow cube, but I'm encountering issues with noticeable gaps between the walls. Despite adjusting the Extrusion multiplier and width settings, the results remain unchanged. Can someone provide guidance on how to address this issue or suggest alternative parameters to tweak for a more solid print?

- Filament Used: eSun ePLA-HS High-Speed Filament 1.75 mm
- Bed Temp: 60 °C
- Nozzle Temp: 220 °C

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While the question is tagged with a slicer tag, this clearly should need at least a tag of the printer, this is most probably not a slicer issue but a hardware issue.

Comment: I was not able to tag the printer but the printer  I'm using is Creat-bot F430

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What could be the underlying reasons for the spaces or voids between the layers?

**Underextrusion** is what is called the phenomenon you see.

For a calibrated printer, which is pretty much how you get them delivered, there should not be any fiddling with the extrusion multiplier parameter necessary to get reasonable prints.

When underextrusion appears in your prints, this usually suggests that something is wrong in the extruder to spool to nozzle path.

Many of the underextrusion can be related to e.g. (this is an example list and may not be complete, but, given the question it is hard to pinpoint to a specific issue):

- Too much friction on the spool,

  - Entangled, or tight winded filament
  - Too much friction in unrolling/turning the spool
- Obstructions in the nozzle

  - Carbonized debris in the nozzle
  - Problems with the PTFE tube in the heat break
- Problems with the extruder

  - Slipping/skipping filament; not enoungh force to move the filament
  - Grinding filament; too much force to move the filament
- etc.

You need to do some troubleshooting, inspecting and cleaning of the complete extrusion path and address any problem you encounter.

Comment: Thank you for the information . I've taken apart the extruder and examined the heat-break and it look like  the PTFE tube is worn out.

Comment: @S_D Thanks for the feedback and good to see the problem you faced falls in the category `Problems with the PTFE tube in the heat break`